# List and copy of list (what is the difference?)

Tags: python

This is my first question ever - sorry if bit trivial

I wonder what is the difference (is there any?) between this two methods

Method A

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'goldfish']  
pets = animals[:] 

animals.sort()
pets.append('donkey')

print(animals)
print(pets)
```

Method B

```
animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'goldfish']
pets = list(animals)

animals.sort()
pets.append('donkey')

print(animals)
print(pets)
```

In method A copy of list is created and assigned to new variable (pets)

In method B new list is created and assigned to pets?

(not sure if I'm right)  Do we creating list in method A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will copy the list stored in the `animals` variable and assign it to `pets` variable. The copy is by value and not by reference, so changing an item in the list assigned to `pets` won't change the list assigned to `animals` and vice-versa